# HTML select input has a different size on IOS devices compared to that of android and windows devices

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive-design, selectinput

Is there a CSS Property that can be used to style it specifically for IOS devices so that it can look like that of windows and android?[image: IOS ViewAndroid and windows view]

I tried using -webkit but it didn't really work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Safari makes it different, but it is possible to remove the appearance and style it with webkit and appearance.

```
 -webkit-appearance: none;
 -moz-appearance: none;
 appearance: none;
```

Check this select example.
https://codepen.io/FlashBuddy/pen/zYYOpgL